# Displaying data from Cryptocoin charts API with PHP

Tags: javascript, php, api, bitcoin, valueconverter

**Hey Stackoverflow,**

I've set myself a little project to celebrate the rise of cryptocurrency (having just been stitched up by a conventional bank myself with some incredibly 'un-Christmassy' charges, the growing use of a decentralized currency was a most welcomed revelation).

Basically, I want to be able to display data on my website from the following API:

http://www.cryptocoincharts.info/v2/api/listCoins

As (at least I believe) this will then enable me to use javascript to carry out my own exchange calculations using the data found there as a base rate, which I can then turn into a form to create as an easy to use exchange calculator.

This is what I have so far...

**The example PHP from cryptocoincharts:**

```
// fetch data
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.cryptocoincharts.info/v2/api/listCoins");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$rawData = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);

// decode to array
$data = json_decode($rawData);

// show data
echo "<pre>";
foreach ($data as $row) echo $row->id." - ".$row->name."\n";
echo "</pre>";
```

**Javascript for the exchange calculations:**

```
    <script language="JavaScript">
    <!--
    function goldConverter(){
    document.converter.bitcoin.value = document.converter.gold.value * 0.05019370
    document.converter.litecoin.value = document.converter.gold.value * 1.56379100
    document.converter.peercoin.value = document.converter.gold.value * 7.52631578
    }
    function bitcoinConverter(){
    document.converter.gold.value = document.converter.bitcoin.value * 19.92281899
    document.converter.litecoin.value = document.converter.bitcoin.value * 0.03210000
    document.converter.peercoin.value = document.converter.bitcoin.value * 0.00667000
    }
    </script>
```

To further clarify my intention is to enable (more or less) real-time automated update of the exchange values using the data from cyrptocoincharts, figures listed above are there for the purpose of testing.

**And here is my HTML:**

```
    <form name="converter">
    <table border="0">
    <tr>
    <td>Gold (g): </td><td><input type="text" name="gold" onChange="goldConverter()" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Bitcoin: </td><td><input type="text" name="bitcoin" onChange="bitcoinConverter()" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Litecoin:</td><td><input type="text" name="litecoin" onChange="litecoinConverter()" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td colspan="2" align="center"><input type="button" value="Convert" /></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    </form>
```

**Summary:**

If anyone could either point me in the right direction (particularly regarding the API), or help me get this to work as a whole, I would really appreciate it and give credit where due, I realize I have a lot of learning to do and this is my first post on stackoverflow, so apologies if I have broken any unwritten rules.

**UPDATE:**

I have recently discovered money.js which potentially solves my problem, and I am currently attempting to change the data source from OpenExchange Rates API to Cryptocoin Charts API.

**UPDATE 2.0:**

Now using simple_html_dom.php to scrape the HTML page as seems most straight forward method, however I am receiving the following errors:

> Warning: include_once(simple_html_dom.php) [function.include-once]:
>   failed to open stream: No such file or directory in
>   /srv/disk13/1587290/www/bildungsroman.me.pn/index.php on line 22
>
> Warning: include_once() [function.include]: Failed opening
>   'simple_html_dom.php' for inclusion
>   (include_path='.:/usr/local/php-5.3.22/share/pear') in
>   /srv/disk13/1587290/www/bildungsroman.me.pn/index.php on line 22
>
> Fatal error: Call to undefined function file_get_html() in
>   /srv/disk13/1587290/www/bildungsroman.me.pn/index.php on line 25

My new code is as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

  <head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <title>title</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">


  </head>

  <body>

    <!-- page content -->


    <?php
    include_once('simple_html_dom.php');

    $html = file_get_html('http://www.cryptocoincharts.info/v2/api/listCoins');

    $result = $html -> find('name');

    foreach($result as $element) {
        echo $element."<br/>";
    }
    ?>

  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The above PHP script should be in the simple_html_dom.php directory, or use an absolute path instead of the relative path you've used.